# When will the next official version of MSAL.JS be dropped on GitHub

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal

There are several updates that have been made in the MSAL.JS library on:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java

Question is, when will the next major drop be made and where will the list of updates be included?  There several updates that have been made that correct multiple problems that a customer of mine is waiting on to resolve their issue.  Specifically, they are asking when will:
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/74

Be included.  The lasted version was 6 months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Microsoft extensively the past few weeks on this library, and apparently they're going to be cutting a release this week for MSAL.JS which will include PR 74 as that's caused us a lot of issues too. I'll keep you up to date if I get a finite date/time.